# ejabberd filter_packet hook not working on Elixir

Tags: erlang, xmpp, elixir, hook, ejabberd

I am following this example, and It seems that the API has changed. The first `on_filter_packet` is never called, just the empty `on_filter_packet` that only returns the packet. Any clues?

```
defmodule PacketFilter do
  import Ejabberd.Logger
  @behaviour :gen_mod

  def start(_host, _opts) do
    info('Starting ejabberd module Filter Packet Demo')
    Ejabberd.Hooks.add(:filter_packet, :global, __ENV__.module, :on_filter_packet, 50)
    :ok
  end

  def stop(_host) do
    info('Stopping ejabberd module Filter Packet Demo')
    Ejabberd.Hooks.delete(:filter_packet, :global, __ENV__.module, :on_filter_packet, 50)
    :ok
  end

  def on_filter_packet({from, to, xml={:xmlel, "message", attributes, children}} = packet) do
    # this hook is never called.
    # What I want only packets of type `message` here.

    info("on_filter_packet [1] #{inspect packet}")
    packet
  end

  def on_filter_packet(packet) do
    # always called, without this hook, the ejabberd throws a lot of erros.
    info("on_filter_packet [2] #{inspect packet}")
    packet
  end

end
```

1 - https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-with-elixir-packet-filters/

Comment: Can you share some snippets from your code and also show how you are running it? I don't know how you are using the code in the article. Also, at first glance I don't see the article specifying an ejabberd version. You might contact the author and ask for clarification on that.

Comment: `ejabberd` is an open source project, isn’t it? What is the problem to go read it’s code to check whether the API has changed or not?

Comment: Sure, updated with the snippet.